# HTML Simplest hide/show and class filter

Tags: javascript, html, filter

I have searched far and wide for this but can't quite find what I need.
I have a list as such:

```
<ul>
    <li class="a b c">Apple</li>
    <li class="a">Banana</li>
    <li class="b">Carrot</li>
    <li class="b c">Drink</li>
</ul>
```

All I need is 3 buttons that toggle variables true and false that will show/hide the list items with the corresponding class for each variable. Then a search box that will filter out the list items without the (not case sensitive) string in them. For instance checking the box labelled "a" will only show "Apple" and "Banana" but typing in "b" into the search box will only show "Banana".

This is what I have tried so far:

```
<button onClick="toggle(a)">A</button>
<button onClick="toggle(b)">B</button>
<button onClick="toggle(c)">C</button>
<ul>
    <li class="a b c">Apple</li>
    <li class="a">Banana</li>
    <li class="b">Carrot</li>
    <li class="b c">Drink</li>
</ul>
```

Then the Javascript:

```
var a, b, c;
function toggle(i) {
    if (i) {i = false
    }else {i = true};
};

if (a) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('a').style.visibility='shown';
}else {
    document.getElementsByClassName('a').style.visibility='hidden';
};

if (b) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('b').style.visibility='shown';
}else {
    document.getElementsByClassName('b').style.visibility='hidden';
};

if (c) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('c').style.visibility='shown';
}else {
    document.getElementsByClassName('c').style.visibility='hidden';
};
```

I have not yet figured out how to take a string from a text box.

How would I do this as simply as possible. "Simplest" being with the least code and vanilla javascript with no surplus features. I do not need animation or fancy graphics, just a show and hide based on the criteria. I will also note I'm reasonably new to JS and just cannot understand JQuery at all.

Thanks in advance.

Olie.

Also: If I have missed another question requesting the same info then do tell me.

Comment: Offtopic in stackoverflow

Comment: I asked a question: "How can I do this as simply as possible?". It is on the topic of coding. I honestly do not see where the "off topic"ness is.

Comment: Doesn't really seem off topic to me either.  Downvotes will likely be because you didn't show what you have tried so far.  That said i'm working on an answer

Comment: It's because you don't read the help center before ask a question. You'll find "*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*"

Comment: There are also 3 closing votes to the "Too broad" closing section.

Comment: **Too broad**: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Ok I will add what I have tried so far in an attempt to make it less vague.

Comment: Also Marcos, I am not asking to find a "book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource"

Comment: It's worth pointing out that asking for a "smplest" or "best" solution lends the question to the "opinion-based" close vote reason. I'm not voting to close, because the question is answerable, but you have to define the criteria for "simplest," or "best," in order that those answering can work within your criteria.

Comment: Ok I'll put that edit in as well. By "simplest" I did assume that meaning "as little code or surplus features as possible"

Comment: That was my assumption; but it's worth asking questions defensively sometimes, for guidance to asking questions here on Stack Overflow check out the "[ask]" and "[mcve]" guidelines. We're not deliberately hostile to newcomers - though it can definitely feel that way, I'm sure - but we do actively prune the questions so that only the 'good' ones - so far as possible - are retained, that might be of help to others in future. That aside, though: welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry if it's overwhelming at first.

Comment: Ok that does help. I will keep all this in mind for future questions. Though it would be a little better if the problems were named and improvements suggested before just deleting posts as it has on me before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created toggle buttons for your three classes, and an input that sets visibility based on the content of your list items.

**Javascript**

```
var hiddenClass = [];
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('toggleBtn');
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    var self = this;
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(self.value);
    toggleButtonState(self);
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      var element = elements[i];

      var isHidden = false;
      var classes = element.className.split(' ');
      for(var j = 0; j < classes.length; j++){
        if(hiddenClass.indexOf(classes[j]) !== -1) isHidden = true;
      }

      var vis = elements[i].style.visibility;
      if(vis === 'hidden' && !isHidden){
        setVisibility(element, 'visible');
      } else {
        setVisibility(element, 'hidden');
      }
    }
  });  
}

var input = document.getElementById('classFilter');

input.addEventListener('input', function(){
  var food = document.getElementsByClassName('food');
  for(var i = 0; i < food.length; i++){
    var ele = food[i];
    if(ele.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.value.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
      setVisibility(ele, 'hidden');
    }else {
      isHidden = false;
      var classes = ele.className.split(' ');
      for(var j = 0; j < classes.length; j++){
        if(hiddenClass.indexOf(classes[j]) !== -1) isHidden = true;
      }

      if(!isHidden) setVisibility(ele, 'visible');
    }
  }
});

function setVisibility(element, visibility){
  element.style.visibility = visibility;
}

function setVisibilityByClass(name, visibility) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(name);
  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    setVisibility(elements[i], visibility);
  }
}

function toggleButtonState(element){
  var on = element.className.indexOf('on') !== -1;
  if(on){
    element.className = 'toggleBtn off';
    if(hiddenClass.indexOf(element.value) === -1) hiddenClass.push(element.value);
  }
  if(!on){
    element.className = 'toggleBtn on';
    hiddenClass = hiddenClass.filter(function(x) { return x !== element.value });
  }  
}
```

**Html**

```
<div id="buttons">
  <input type="button" class="toggleBtn on" value="a" />
  <input type="button" class="toggleBtn on" value="b"   />
  <input type="button" class="toggleBtn on" value="c"   />

  <input type="text" id="classFilter"  />
</div>

<ul>
    <li class="food a b c">Apple</li>
    <li class="food a">Banana</li>
    <li class="food b">Carrot</li>
    <li class="food b c">Drink</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
  .off {
    background-color: grey;
  }
```

Got a fiddle working, had to change the listeners a bit to work in their environment: https://jsfiddle.net/b9jp7m1g/1/

Comment: This works perfectly and is exactly what I was looking for. If this is allowed then can I ask how I would display the buttons differently depending on if their variable is true or false?

Comment: Ah yeah I think I see what you mean, it gets a little confusing because the textbox alters their state but i'll try to get something working

Comment: Also after a bit of testing, the search box filter seems not to work.

Comment: Right now it functions independently of the buttons and sets visibility based only on what you type, should it behave differently?

Comment: It should filter both in real time but prioritize the class. So as I start typing "banana" in the box it should hide the list items without that in it but if I have class "a" hidden then it would return no results.

Comment: Oh I see I thought it was supposed to look at class names as well, not the string in the list item -- i'll try to get that fixed too :)

Comment: Updated the code, not sure if it is 100% bug free but I think I addressed most of your concerns.  Make sure to throw the css bit in so you can tell which buttons are toggled on/off

Comment: I have gone through and replaced everything that needs to be and the buttons work exceedingly well. However the text box still doesn't seem to affect it. Could this be because there is other content in the list item? I don't have the text I want to test to filter in any tags but I have a description in <p> tags.

Comment: I changed the startsWith to a more general indexOf, it should now show records that match the text typed anywhere inside of the list item

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the code or something else but this search bar is not playing nice. I replaced the js and triple-checked the html and it is still not working.

Comment: could you paste the html into a fiddle or something and link me to it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107884/discussion-between-irkeninvader-and-olie-ayre).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. How I hide and show DOM elements that can be or impact several different areas is as follows:
1)  I create a CSS as follow:

```
.hideDom {
    display: none;
}
```

2) Then within the code area I toggle that css "on" and "off" to hide and show the DOM element(s) as follows:

```
$('someSelector').removeClass("hideDom");
```

to hide and

```
$('someSelector').addClass("hideDom");
```

to show. So for example, if I wanted to hide several DOM elements when "condition1" occurs, else show the elements. I would put a class on all those elements say 'cssCondition1' and perform the following:

```
switch(condition){
   case "condition1":
      $('.cssCondition').addClass("hideDom");
      break;
   default:
      $('.cssCondition').removeClass("hideDom");
      break;
}
```

In your specific example, if you wanted to hide everything but the banana:

```
$('.b').addClass("hideDom");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can do this cleanly in an HTML 5 way, using only native JavaScript. This doesn't use class names, but keys off the actual lowercased data. It will also shows a basic example of how jQuery uses the $ as a function name, plus how it works from a native JS POV. Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/q58hn2yd/) for this demo.

HTML:

```
<button data-key="a">A</button>
<button data-key="b">B</button>
<button data-key="c">C</button>
<button data-key="d">D</button>
<button data-key="all">Show All</button>
<ul>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Carrot</li>
    <li>Drink</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
/* This is a basic example of how jQuery works, 
 * but with native JavaScript & without jQuery:
 */
function $(str) {
  if (str.indexOf(' ') > -1) {
    var results = document.querySelectorAll(str);
  } else if (str[0] === '#') {
    var results = document.getElementById(str.replace('#',''));
  } else if (str[0] === '.') {
    var results = document.getElementsByClassName(str.replace('.',''));
  } else {
    var results = document.getElementsByTagName(str);
  }
  return results;
}

// So you can use dollar sign function names, as shortcuts, as shown below:
function showAll(liTags) { // This is useful for the next button click.
  if (!liTags) {
     liTags = $('li');
  }
  for (var i=0; i<liTags.length; i++) {
    var liTag = liTags[i];
    liTag.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
}

function clickHandler() {
  var key = this.dataset.key; // Gets the data-key attribute.
  var liTags = $('li');
  showAll(liTags);

  if (key !== 'all') {
    // Hide all but current one.
    for (var i=0; i<liTags.length; i++) {
      var liTag = liTags[i];
      var text = liTag.innerText.toLowerCase();
      if (text.indexOf(key) > -1) {
        liTag.style.visibility = 'visible';
      } else {
        liTag.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
    }
  }
}

(function init() {
   var results = $('button');
   for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
       results[i].addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
   }
})(); // Self-loading function, which runs only 1x on Page Load.
```